# Flutter - How to rebuild a future widget from another widget

Tags: flutter

I tried to make the code below simple as possible, I have no idea what approach I should be trying to take.

I have a future builder that returns weather API data.
I have a timer to stop spamming of API.
But how can I get the weather widget to reload so the FutureBuilder is called again?

**main.dart**

```
  CurrentWeatherWidget(),
```

**current_weather_widget.dart**

```
  return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    FutureBuilder<CurrentWeatherFactory>(
        future: main,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData)
          {
           >> DISPLAY WIDGET
          } else if (snapshot.hasError)
          {
            return Text(snapshot.error);
          }
CircularProgressIndicator(),
```

**some_other_widget.dart**

```
RaisedButton(
onPressed: (){
    if (timer() == 0){
        timerReset();
        >> RELOAD current_weather_.dart

    } else {
        print("no new data");
    }

    },
    child: Text('RELOAD NEW DATA'),
```

),

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest replacing the FutureBuilder with a [`StreamBuilder`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) and updating the stream every time new weather data is available. So instead of using a Future you could use a [`BehaviorSubject`](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/rxdart/latest/rx/BehaviorSubject-class.html) and call its add method to update the stream.